# How to set the default namespace using JAXB

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb, atom-feed

I have a ATOM-XML representation of my data that is returned via a Spring MVC web service. I'm using JAXB to do the serialization, I have a number of namespaces but I want the default namespace set to Atom with no prefix. Here is what I have so far in `package-info.java`  but the atom prefix is being set to ns3.

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = com.mycomponay.foo.ATOM_NAMESPACE,
xmlns = { 
    @XmlNs(prefix = "foo", namespaceURI = com.mycomponay.foo.NAMESPACE_FOO),
}, elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.mycompany.web;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
```

Also I noticed the namespaces display in chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: just curious: why do you mind what namespace prefix is used?

Answer (score 12):

Try adding an `@XmlNs` annotation with prefix `""` for the namespace you want to appear as the default.

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = com.mycompany.foo.ATOM_NAMESPACE,
    xmlns = { 
        @XmlNs(prefix = "", namespaceURI = com.mycompany.foo.ATOM_NAMESPACE),
        @XmlNs(prefix = "foo", namespaceURI = com.mycompany.foo.NAMESPACE_FOO)
    }, 
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.mycompany.web;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**Note:**

The namespaces specified in the `@XmlSchema` annotation are meant to affect the generation of the XML Schema and are not guaranteed to be used when a object model is marshalled to XML.  However [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) and recent versions of the [JAXB reference implementation](https://jaxb.java.net/) will use them whenever possible.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html

Comment: Thanks Blaise, but that didn't work the ATOM namespace is being set to 'ns4'. I'm using Spring MVC which uses a `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` I tried to extend that and add set the  `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper ` property with my custom `NamespacePrefixMapper`  but with no luck.

Comment: I have got it working with my custom `NamespacePrefixMapper` and it is being called. Now I'm presented with another issue, by the time my custom `NamespacePrefixMapper` is called the empty prefix is already taken by the `defaultNsUri` which is hard coded in `JAXBContextImpl`. Does any one know a solution to this issue?

Comment: Isn't `XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX` preferred?

Comment: This is correct answer for the question. Still you have to define @XmlRootElement(name="name") without namespace parameter to the root element annotation. Otherwise ns1.. like namespaces will get added.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using separate class for XML element, annotate it with namespace="", would work.