# How to set default namespace with JAXB (JDK 7)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I've got problem with setting default namespace with JAXB. I have followed tips from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478317/how-to-set-the-default-namespace-using-jaxb) but problem still exist. Here is how looks like my package-info:

```
@XmlSchema(
        namespace = "my/xml/namespace",
        xmlns = {
                @XmlNs(namespaceURI="my/xml/namespace",prefix=""),
        },
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package my.xml.namespace;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;;
```

But still created xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:resp xmlns:ns2="my/xml/namespace">
....
</ns2:resp>
```

I would like to get rid of these prefix but run out of ideas. Anyone maybe know why?

**UPDATE**

I habe followed advice and implement NamespacePrefixMapper and:

1. It's crucial to be com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper. I've use another one and get wierd exceptions.
2. It does not work too - the same issue persist. Here is my mapper:

   NamespacePrefixMapper mapper = new NamespacePrefixMapper(){

   ```
           @Override
           public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix)
           {
               if("amc/xml/pay03_entryresponse".equals(namespaceUri)) {
                   return "";
               }else return suggestion;
           }

       };
       marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", mapper);
   ```

Comment: I am having this issue as well. Haven't seen a solution yet.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a Namespace mapper.

There are some examples on the web:

- http://hwellmann.blogspot.co.at/2011/03/jaxb-marshalling-with-custom-namespace.html
- http://java.dzone.com/articles/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes

Comment: I think I read somewhere that with jdk 7 it is dissallowed to use it. But if you suggest so I will try.

Comment: NamespacePrefixMapper is considered implementation details and it is not part of Java API. You will be exposed to risk when moving to another java vendor.

Comment: @PastorPL, yes it will lead to a PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper