# XSD from XML Java Jaxb

Tags: java, xsd, namespaces, jaxb

**I need to generate in Java the xsd file which using jaxb maven plugin** (http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/xjc-mojo.html) will produce an XML like the following:

```
<data xmlns = "http://foo.com">
    <childData xmlns = "http://bar.com" />
</data>
```

I don't want to edit the jaxb autogenerated classes or something like that.

I've already checked similar topics and I haven't found any solution yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "to generate in Java"? A simple XSD can be written in an editor - far from rocket science.

Comment: @JordiCastilla It seems OP doesn't

Comment: I want to know which will be the XSD file because I tried with several xsd files and I didn't found any which generate the given output

Comment: Well, simply ask for the XSD file and I'll try.

Comment: http://the-music-of-time.blogspot.com.es/2006/10/jaxb-jibx-and-reverse-engineering-xsd.html

Comment: Finally I achieved the desired behaviour looking at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720501/jaxb-marshalling-xmpp-stanzas/5722013#5722013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is xxx.xsd, defining the outer element in the foo namespace:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:foo="http://foo.com"
        targetNamespace="http://foo.com"
        xmlns:bar="http://bar.com"
        jaxb:version="2.0">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://bar.com" 
              schemaLocation="yyy.xsd"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="DataType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="bar:childData"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:element name="data" type="foo:DataType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

And here is yyy.xsd:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
            targetNamespace="http://bar.com"
            xmlns:bar="http://bar.com"
            jaxb:version="2.0">
  <xsd:element name="childData" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

**Later** The usual Java code for marshalling:

```
 void marshal() throws Exception {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.foo:com.bar" );
    Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
    DataType data = new DataType();
    ObjectFactory of = new ObjectFactory();
    JAXBElement<DataType> jbe = of.createData(data);
    data.setChildData("child data");
    m.marshal( jbe, System.out );
}
```

produces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:data xmlns="http://bar.com" xmlns:ns2="http://foo.com">  
  <childData>child data</childData>
</ns2:data>
```

which is equivalent to the XML you have posted.

Comment: I understand that it's equivalent but I need the same XML not an equivalent version

Comment: It is the "same" XML even when it is not an identical text.

Comment: I'm sorry but I need the identical text, I've already generated some equivalent versions. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Not by asking for an XML Schema or similar. You'll have to use StringBuilder, PrintWriter, etc. It's not XML according to W3C.

Comment: @user3698770: laune is correct that you should not worry about about textual equivalence but rather XML equivalenace, but you can try experimenting with JAXB's `@XmlNs` annotation mechanism with an empty (`""`) namespace prefix [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478317/how-to-set-the-default-namespace-using-jaxb) if you insist.

Comment: @kjhughes This requires writing or at least editing the xjc-generated Java sources.

Comment: I understand your explanations, so without editing anything is not possible to generate exactly the same XML string. Right?

Comment: Correct. There is nothing in XML Schema or JAXB annotations that requires a particular way of defining the XML namespace(s) in a certain way. Correct XML readers should handle all correct ways; XML writers aren't required to provide options for the various ways it could be done. - Note that it is possible that a *complex* type for `childData` might subtly change the way xjc generates code, possibly resulting in a different XML output. But it is definitely not advisable to rely on the way a certain xjc version happens to generate Java code.