# jaxb namespace gives unneeded ns2 prefix

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces

I need to generate the namespace into the xml, but this leads to an inconsistent ns2 prefixing that I don't need (I don't have mixed namespaces). I tried several solutions i found with no luck.

package-info.java

```
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace="http://namespace" ,
        elementFormDefault=javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        xmlns={
        @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI="http://namespace", prefix="")
        })

    package hu.xml.create;
```

POJO

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "create", namespace = "http://namespace")
    public class Create{
    ...
```

marshaller

```
    public String mashal(Object object) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(object.getClass());
        Marshaller mar= context.createMarshaller();
        mar.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        mar.marshal(object, sw);

        return sw.toString();
}
```

call

```
    @RequestMapping("/export/{id}")
    public String export(Model model, @PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {
        String method = "export";
    
        Create create = new Create(...);
        try {
            String xml = RequestHandler.getInstance().mashal(create);
            model.addAttribute("xml", xml);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        return "export";
}
```

result

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <ns2:create xmlns:ns2="http://namespace">
        <ns2:tag>
            <subtag>true</subtag>
```

Comment: How does your desired XML result differ from the actual XML result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the default namespace using JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478317/how-to-set-the-default-namespace-using-jaxb)

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz as far as I can tell, that answer contains the same thing I implemented.

Comment: @kjhughes I don't want any prefixes

Comment: @LanceToth, I noticed later and posted an answer, but forgot to delete the comment. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace prefix is needed, since you have elements like `<subtag>` without a namespace. Once you assign a namespace to them, the `ns2` prefix will disappear and JAXB will use a default namespace as your required.

There is also a comment in `NamespaceContextImpl#declareNsUri` of JAXB RI that states:

```
// the default prefix is already taken.
// move that URI to another prefix, then assign "" to the default prefix.
```

**Edit:** If you cannot get rid of the unqualified elements, you can qualify them with the same namespace as the other elements. This is possible at least with JAXB RI and is equivalent to a `<xsd:include>` tag:

```
final Map<String, String> props = Collections.singletonMap(JAXBRIContext.DEFAULT_NAMESPACE_REMAP, "http://namespace");
final JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{Create.class}, props);
```

Comment: the tag in question contains a POJO with identification information that I need to send in different requests, all with their own namespace

Comment: If you accept to include those unqualified elements into the main namespace, you can proceed as in the edited answer. The generated XML will, however, not be equivalent to the one you get now.

Comment: I added what I could to the proper namespace and created subclasses for the class that is used in multiple namespaces. Not an elegant solution, but it works

Comment: You can also [play with this gist](https://gist.github.com/ppkarwasz/41300cbcc50d75316903fe426b8be9c3) to check how namespace remapping work.